# Same SQL Query Slower from NHibernate Application than SQL Studio?

Tags: sql, sql-server, nhibernate

Our application issues an NHibernate-generated SQL query.  At application runtime, the query takes about 12 seconds to run against a SQL Server database.  SQL Profiler shows over 500,000 reads.

However, if I capture the exact query text using SQL Profiler, and run it again from SQL Studio, it takes 5 seconds and shows less than 4,600 reads.

The query uses a couple of parameters whose values are supplied at the end of the SQL text, and I'd read a little about parameter sniffing and inefficient query plans, but I had thought that related to stored procedures.  Maybe NHibernate holds the resultset open while it instantiates its entities, which could explain the longer duration, but what could explain the extra 494,000 "reads" for the same query as performed by NHibernate?  (No additional queries appear in the SQL Profiler trace.)

The query is specified as a LINQ query using NHibernate 3.1's LINQ facility.  I didn't include the query itself because it seems like a basic question of philosophy: what could explain such a dramatic difference?

In case it's pertinent, there also happens to be a varbinary(max) column in the results, but in our situation it always contains null.

Any insight is much appreciated!

Comment: Parameter sniffing also applies to adhoc parameterised queries not just stored procedures. The plans for these get compiled according to the first set of parameters and reused for subsequent invocations with possibly different parameter values too.

Comment: Did you ever figure out the issue? I'm running into the same thing, and all of my parameters are ints so I don't see how that could be an issue.

Answer (score 2):

Be sure to read: http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html

Same rules apply for procs and sp_executesql. A huge reason for shoddy plans can be passing in a `nvarchar` param for a `varchar` field, it causes index scans as opposed to seeks.

I very much doubt the output is affecting the perf here, it is likely to be an issue with one of the params sent in, or selectivity of underlying tables.

When testing your output from profiler, be sure to include `sp_executesql` and make sure your settings match (stuff like `SET ARITHABORT`), otherwise you will cause a new plan to be generated.

You can always dig up the shoddy plan from the execution cache via `sys.dm_exec_query_stats`

Comment: does the same thing apply for INT vs BIGINT?

Comment: @Phill no it seems SQL is happy to use the correct index in that case

Comment: Ok cool, we have a legacy database where the original developer was thinking big. (database is 10 years old) all new tables are INT but with foreign key reference to BIGINT. You had me worried for a moment that it could cause performance issues!

Comment: @Phill I do not think you will get perf issues there, but something about that design feels wrong.

Comment: Yes, the use of BIGINT... on tables that will only ever have less than 100 records... We are slowly cleaning it up. These were design decision made like 8+ years ago. But now that the databases are > 500gb, trying to cut down on things like using BIGINT where a TINYINT would be better.